# Linq Array List order changes

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, linq, entity-framework

Hi I have a array which picks up manufacturer and country, for some reason when the array comes back the order of the array sometimes changes.

Here is the Linq query:

```
  var array = (from xx in _er.UserRoles
                         join xy in _er.Countries on xx.CountryId equals xy.Id
                         join xz in _er.Manufacturers on xx.ManufacturerId equals xz.Id
                         where xx.UserId == userId
                         select new List<string> { xz.Description, xy.Name }).ToArray();
```

Where:
xz.Description is manufacturer
xy.Name is country

In my array I expect to get the following:

```
[0]    Count = 2
   [0] Dove
   [1] Uk
[1]    Count = 2
   [0] Dove
   [1] France
[2]    Count = 2
   [0] Sure
   [1] UK
...
```

However in some cases I am getting the following:

```
[0]    Count = 2
   [0] Dove
   [1] Uk
[1]    Count = 2
   [0] France
   [1] Dove
[2]    Count = 2
   [0] UK
   [1] Sure
...
```

When i run the query in the db to check that each Manufacturer has a country they do as initially i thought it may be that.

Could anyone make suggestion on why this may be happening?

**Edit**

Here is the sql query and some sample data:

```
select m.Description, c.Name from UserRoles ur
join Countries c on ur.CountryId = c.Id
join Manufacturers m on ur.ManufacturerId = m.Id
where ur.userid = 435
```

Example data:

```
Description     Name
Lynx        United Kingdom
Persil      United Kingdom
Dove        Brazil
Dove        Canada
Dove        Germany
Dove        France
Dove        United Kingdom
Dove        Netherlands
Dove        United States
Surf        United Kingdom
Comfort     United Kingdom
Sure        United Kingdom
Bertolli        United Kingdom
Bertolli        United States
```

**Edit 2**

Here is a bit more explanation of what I am doing so may explain more about what i need as a end result:

In my controller I am getting the array to put into a session:

Controller code:

```
  var userManuCountry = _userRoleRepository.GetCountryAndManufacturerForUser(u.Id);
  Session["userManuCountry"] = userManuCountry;
```

Repository code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userId"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string[,] GetCountryAndManufacturerForUser(int userId)
        {

            var array = (from xx in _er.UserRoles
                         join xy in _er.Countries on xx.CountryId equals xy.Id
                         join xz in _er.Manufacturers on xx.ManufacturerId equals xz.Id
                         where xx.UserId == userId
                         select new List<string> { xz.Description, xy.Name }).ToArray();
            return CreateRectangularArray(array);

        }


        static T[,] CreateRectangularArray<T>(IList<T>[] arrays)
        {
            // TODO: Validation and special-casing for arrays.Count == 0
            int minorLength = arrays[0].Count();
            T[,] ret = new T[arrays.Length, minorLength];
            for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Length; i++)
            {
                var array = arrays[i];
                if (array.Count != minorLength)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException
                        ("All arrays must be the same length");
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < minorLength; j++)
                {
                    ret[i, j] = array[j];
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Another controller - i am using the session to list the countries for the manufacturer:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// et the specific countries for user and manufacturer
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        //  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        // [Authorize(Roles = "ReportingDashboardAccess")]
        public ActionResult GetListOfCountriesForUserManufacturer(int userId, string manu)
        {
            manu = manu.Trim();
            // get the specific countries for user and manufacturer
            var countries = new List<string>();              

            //here we want to use the manu to get the countries from seesion rather than db - this is a multidimensional array
            string[,] manuCountry = (string[,])Session["userManuCountry"];

            var addCountry = false;
            //loop through to find countries for each manufacturer
            for (int row = 0; row < manuCountry.GetLength(0); row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < manuCountry.GetLength(1); col++)
                {
                    string result = manuCountry[row, col];
                    result.Trim();
                    if (addCountry == true && col == 1)
                    {
                        //addcountry has been set to true so add it
                        countries.Add(result);
                        addCountry = false;
                    }
                    else if (addCountry == true && col == 0)
                    {
                        addCountry = false;
                    }
                    if (result == manu)
                    {
                        //the next one that comes through is the country
                        addCountry = true;

                    }


                }
            }

            countries.Sort();
            ViewData["allCountries"] = new SelectList(countries);


            return View("CountriesParam");

        }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: You need to explicitly order your results, otherwise ordering will be handed off to SQL. Depending on whether you have any primary keys on a table, it may not always return the same order

Comment: Please provide DB schama and some sample data.

Comment: @RGraham should adding  orderby xz.Description ascending be enough?

Comment: @Sunny i have added data to the question and the sql query

Comment: Collection Initializers (`new List<string> { xz.Description, xy.Name }`) are supposed to preserve the ordering of the items as specified in the expression. Are you sure this is the code that is executing?

Comment: @SWeko this is the exact code i am using which is why I am a little confused by the results i am getting

Comment: @RGraham, correct, it will depend on the query plan used to service the query and could be greatley affected by parallelization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collection Initializers (`new List<string> { xz.Description, xy.Name }`) are supposed to preserve the ordering of the items as specified in the expression, so your code should work.

I would guess that there is something that operates on the created list and somehow fungles the ordering.

That said, using a list (or any collection) for values that have separate meanings is non-intuitive. Even if they are both strings, the values do not have the same context. It would be much better to give them explicitly different containers. e.g. right now, if you fill a couple of textboxes with the data, you would use:

```
txtName.Text = list[0];
txtCountry.Text = list[1];
```

and a bug will be hard to see and diagnose. If you put the results in a separate entity (anonymous class for example) using

```
select new { Name = xz.Description, Country = xy.Name }
```

you could use

```
txtName.Text = myObject.Name;
txtCountry.Text = myObject.Country
```

---

Regarding edit2: If I understand your scenario correctly, what you need is to get a list of allowed countries for a manufacturer. A great container for such data would be a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>`, instead of a `string[,]`.

I would refactor the LINQ like this:

```
//gets the data from the database
var data = (from xx in _er.UserRoles
                     join xy in _er.Countries on xx.CountryId equals xy.Id
                     join xz in _er.Manufacturers on xx.ManufacturerId equals xz.Id
                     where xx.UserId == userId
                     select new { Name = xz.Description, Country = xy.Name });
//formats the data into a dictionary
var result = data.GroupBy(a => a.Name)
                 .ToDictionary(// the name of the product
                               g => g.Key, 
                               // the list of countries for the product
                               g => g.Select(a => a.Country).ToList());
return result;
```

And then use it (in `GetListOfCountriesForUserManufacturer`) like this:

```
public ActionResult GetListOfCountriesForUserManufacturer(int userId, string manu)
{
   manu = manu.Trim();

   //I'm not too crazy about sesiion usage, but that's a whole other issue
   var manuCountry = (Dictionary<string, List<string>>)Session["userManuCountry"];

   // get the specific countries for user and manufacturer
   var countries = manuCountry[manu];
   countries.Sort();
   ViewData["allCountries"] = new SelectList(countries);
   return View("CountriesParam");
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question if you  look at edit 2 do you think i shoudl still be using the method you have described? thanks

Comment: what would the declaration be for dictionary it doens t like    public Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> GetCountryAndManufacturerForUser(int userId)

Comment: Try `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: I m currently getting a Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<string>>' D:\Dev2010\emsTest\ReportingAdmin\Models\UserRoleRepository.cs 206 20 ReportingAdmin
error

Comment: Rewrote the `.ToDictionary` call, try it now.

Comment: thank you @Sweko  i do appreciate it i ve been struggling with this code for a while and i thought my solution was working but the way that  youhave done it using a dictionary makes it is much better

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement you're creating a list which in essence is unordered.
I would advise you to create a new class with a description,name(and maybe more properties) because it seems to me that each item in the list has a specific source rather then being a list.

If you don't want to create a new class you could always put it in a tuple like this :

```
var array = (from xx in _er.UserRoles
                         join xy in _er.Countries on xx.CountryId equals xy.Id
                         join xz in _er.Manufacturers on xx.ManufacturerId equals xz.Id
                         where xx.UserId == userId
                         select new Tuple<string,string> (xz.Description, xy.Name)).ToArray();
```